# How would you flush two characters of arbitrary length using HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css, math

I want to create a worksheet addition of, say, two five digit numbers. Using `text-decoration:underline;`, I get something like the following:

```
12345
+ 12345
-------
```

Wrapping in a `div` and using

```
style="width: 8em; margin: 1em; font-family: courier; text-align: right;"
```

gives me something like the following:

```
 12345
+ 12345
-------
```

which is marginally better than before. How would accomplish aligning the digits on the ones? To be clear, the digits will be the same length, but the best answer would be robust to two digits of size `m` and `n` where `m` does not necessarily equal `n`, but I'm willing to trade robustness for not requiring javascript.

```
  12345
+ 12345
-------
      ^---- align the ones digit
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `text-align: right;` should be all you need... are you sure there isn't an extra space after your first number? or any other CSS that's interfering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was rather fun to put together: **[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qCaP6/5/)**.
**Note: Only tested on Firefox!**

HTML:

```
<div class="worksheet">
    <span>12345</span>
    <span class="add">54321</span>
</div>

<div class="worksheet">
    <span>123</span>
    <span class="sub">45678</span>
</div>

<div class="worksheet">
    <span>54321</span>
    <span class="add">1234</span>
    <span class="sub">987</span>
    <span class="add">1357924</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.worksheet {
    border: 1px dotted #000;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: monospace;
    margin: 0.5em;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: right;
}
.worksheet .add:before {
    content: "+";
    float: left;
    margin-right: 0.5em;
}
.worksheet .sub:before {
    content: "-";
    float: left;
    margin-right: 0.5em;
}
.worksheet span { display: block; }
.worksheet span:last-child {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

Comment: +1, neat, but it might not be robust (the OP uses that word) enough.

Comment: it handles different-sized numbers just fine.. at least, i think that's what the OP meant by 'robust' :D

Comment: Works in Chrome Beta 10 as well. I like the use of the content attribute and pseudoselectors!

Answer (score 3):

I removed `width: 8em` and added `float: left`.

```
<div style="float: left; margin: 1em; font-family: courier; text-align: right;">
12345<br />
+ 66612345<br />
-------
</div>
```

[***Live Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/XckpS/)

I feel like I've misunderstood the problem because this seems too simple a solution :)

Comment: Instead of `float: left` you could use `display: inline-block` :). Otherwise yes, this is the solution.

Comment: I don't know enough CSS, so I probably over-engineer what I do a bit. Sorry for the confusion. Would having float or a display property set even matter for how text aligns? I'm away from my code ATM so I'm not sure what I was doing wrong...

Comment: It doesn't matter for how the text aligns. Setting `float: left` without an explicit width will make the element "shrink wrap" to the size of its content.